# Christoffel symbols:The expression can't be used as part specification error

Tags: differential-equations

[image]

I'm a new user.
I want to ask that what's the problem of my process?
Can anybody teach me?
I'm trying to calculate Christoffel symbols.

```
affine := 
 affine = Simplify[
   Table[(1/2)*
     Sum[(inversemetric[[i, s]])*(D[metric[[s, j]], coord[[k]]] + 
         D[metric[[s, k]], coord[[j]]] - 
         D[metric[[j, k]], coord[[s]]]), {s, l, n}, {i, l, n}, {j, l, 
       n}, {k, l, n}]]]

listaffine := Table[If[UnsameQ[affine[[i, j, k]], 
0], {ToString[\[CapitalGamma][i, j, k]], affine[[i, j, k]]}], {i,1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, j}]

TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listaffine], Null], 2],TableSpacing -> {2, 2}]
```

Comment: Please include your code in textual form for ease of copying and replication.

Comment: I'd try to include my code in the original post, thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do in affine? There is a Table without iterators (those are all in your `Sum`)

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to calculate christoffel symbols, i'm thinking about which part i'd missed